# Can one VS Code syntax scope reference another for theme purposes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

In VS Code, I'd like to have one textmate scope (e.g. punctuation.definition.variable) reference another one (e.g. variable.other.readwrite.global) so that the first element always uses the second element's color. Is that possible?

I am not interested in creating my own theme because I want these changes to be dynamic, to stay in effect regardless of what theme is in use. Specifically, the Perl syntax definition for `$foo` separates the sigil (e.g. `$`) and the variable name (e.g. `foo`) into two separate elements, and I would like to treat them as one.

Comment: What do you mean by element. Like an object, or arrays elements? Can you maybe write up a small snippet of code, in a code example, and reference which elements you want to have the same color?

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.json` you can customize the editor workspace syntax highlighting with `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` and that will apply to every theme unless you specify it for some themes only.

Docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-syntax-highlighting

Here you can find Docs for creating you own rule for syntax highlighting: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide